# trouble with basic conditional

Tags: conditionals

I can't figure out why this conditional does not work. It is a dropdown navigation item in my main nav.

```
    <ul>
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="locations"
        orderby="date"
        sort="asc"
        dynamic="no"
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
    }
        <li{if segment_2=='{url_title}'} class="on"{/if}><a href="{url_title_path='contact'}" title="">{title}</a></li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    </ul>
```

I know segment_2 is the same as the entry's url_title.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the conditional to be parsed after the exp:channel:entries module.

```
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="locations"
    orderby="date"
    sort="asc"
    dynamic="no"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
}
    <li{if "{segment_2}" == "{url_title}"} class="on"{/if}><a href="{url_title_path='contact'}" title="">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```